# Multiple document.onmousemove events not working

Tags: javascript, events, mousemove

i would like some help with a javascript project.What i'm trying to do ,is have two functions that initiate when mouse is moved,but only one of them works every time

For example,if i do this

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

document.onmousemove = captureMouse;
document.onmousemove = function(){console.log("check");}
function captureMouse(ev){
ev = ev || window.event;
var mousePos= mouseCoords(ev);
mouseX=mousePos.x;
mouseY=mousePos.y;
document.getElementById("coordinput").value=mouseX;
return mousePos;}

function mouseCoords(ev){

if(ev.pageX || ev.pageY){

return {x:ev.pageX,y:ev.pageY};


}

 return{
 x:ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft - document.body.clientLeft,
 y:ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  - document.body.clientTop 
 };

}
```

If i remove the second document.onmousemove,the first works fine and changes the values of the input field

If i leave it there,it constantly writes check like it should (it's for debug purposes),but the first one doesn't work

Any ideas on how to make multiple mouse events work?

Comment: As Javascript is sequential, so only the last function assigned to event will be called. In order to check the second function function(){console.log("check");}, you can use it inside the the first function captureMouse;

Comment: Ok thank you for this answer.I thought that each document.onmousemove adds some kind of flag ,so when you move the mouse it executes both,not only the last.The problem is i intend to have a different function in place of console.log so i really need to have them separate,and capturemouse only being there to constantly update the two coordinates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `document.addEventListener('mousemove', yourCb);` it allows multiple handlers

Comment: this actually seems to work.If it's not a hassle,could you please explain why this works,but my code does not? I guess document.onmousemove works like setting onmousemove() on a html element,so i'm basically overwriting it?

Comment: because smth.onmousemove - callback and you overwrite it each time. addEventListener just use smth like array of callbacks internally